# How do we figure out to track facebook app installs to a specific marketing campaign and associated that with our own internal user ID?

Tags: facebook

This seems like a pretty basic need but I am unsure how to do it.  Use case:

1. Company pays FB $$$ for mobile app install.
2. User clicks on facebook add to install your app
3. User starts the app.  The code in the initialization function (appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions on IOS) calls FBAppEvents activateApp]
4. Presumably somewhere in the
   Facebook SDK the IDFA is sent to facebook.
5. Facebook correlates
   the IDFA with the facebook app events to figure out what facebook
   add was clicked.  This data is then fed to facebook analytics so you
   can see what campaign was used.

What I need is that after step 5 completes a way to figure what user ID's are associated with the specific facebook campaign. We would use this in our own internal tools to measure the campaign success.  Preferably I would do this on the mobile end and send up the campaign source.  Alternatively, we could do it server side.  But I just don't see a way to get at the campaign data.

Comment: You can't. You either have to use Facebooks analytics on a thirdparty mobile measure company https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/measuring/measurement-partners

Comment: I am using Facebook analytics.  They seem to have a CSV export option but it is limited.  I don't see any mention of an analytics SDK

Comment: You can get the information on user level. Only aggregated data

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Deferred Deep Linking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking#deferred-deep-linking) with a parameter flagging the campaign install source. You'd miss out on view-through attribution (you could use Ads Manager to scale it up in aggregate), but it'd get you *some* user-level tracking.